# httpclient from apache commons not working on jboss

Tags: java, android, apache, maven, jboss

I have set up logback with slf and jcl over slf in maven project. I also removed all dependencies to commons-logging. The log system works as expected except org.apache.http.wire http client on jboss however it does work fine on tomcat.

Fragments of my maven are:
    
        org.apache.httpcomponents
        httpclient
        4.5
        
            
                commons-logging
                commons-logging

```
<!--Logging-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Edited:I have also added jboss-deployment-structure

```
<deployment>
    <exclude-subsystems>
        <subsystem name="jpa"/>
    </exclude-subsystems>
    <exclusions>
        <module name="javaee.api"/>
        <module name="org.apache.commons.logging"/>
        <module name="org.slf4j"/>
        <module name="org.slf4j.impl"/>
        <module name="org.slf4j.ext"/>
        <module name="org.slf4j.jcl-over-slf4j"/>
        <module name="org.apache.log4j"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.logging.jul-to-slf4j-stub"/>
    </exclusions>
</deployment>
```

Possible solution would be to make commons-logging working in parallel with logback and using another file.

Our jboss version is:
Red Hat JBoss Enterprise Application Platform - Version 6.4.3.GA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try putting the slf4j (or any other logging framework) dependencies in the JBOSS *Boot classpath*. The log system has most likely already initialized before you application (WAR/EAR) deployed.
This could either be a server's `lib` directory or the server's `endorsed` directory. You can put it in `lib` to start with and then based on the version and documentation, you can move it to its proper place if the solution works.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The solution depends on Jboss version and can be more complex. Assuming 7xx version org.apache.commons.logging module is an implicit dependency and it's loaded by default.
More details here:
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Implicit+module+dependencies+for+deployments

If you want to exclude this module, you have to create jboss-deployment-structure.xml file (not tested example):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

More info you can find at:
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7